# nativescript authenticating at backend web api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, angular, nativescript

I am new to mobile development. My project is build using asp.net. For authentication I am using build it UserManager &  User.Identity.

I have bunch of existing web apis  and I wish to use them from mobile app.
I know , I could pass a secret hash to web api after authenticating, but that would involve  a huge code refactoring.

I been wondering if there other ways to handle authentication & authorization with nativescript   & asp.net .

Do you know any useful resources for this topic?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you using the NativeScript-Angular module? If so following the angular2 Auth topics would be a good starter and storing the auth key as George below suggests. Also take a look at the example in GitHub: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/blob/master/ng-sample/app/examples/router/login-test.ts particularly if you are using the newer router.

Comment: My main problem is how to keep backed session going. Asp.net is passing back a auth cookie after a login. I am trying to use @George Edwards comment an save the cookie at appSetting

Comment: @SimeonGrigorovich well my approach is a stateless one - where you don't have to maintain a session (much more scaleable). You just set JWTs to have an expiry time/date and any request with a valid jwt gets authorised. No need to have info on everyone logged in.

Comment: George's approach worked well for my older ionic app with webapi v2+ bearer tokens, but I would have used an interceptor in angular 1. I think I previously added one with cookies (it just needed to be a persistent cookie). I would probably go with the bearer token route with NativeSript + ASP.NET and WebAPI and follow a similar path to @George-Edwards. Each request you just need to add a bearer token to the header. http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/ should be able to help.

Comment: I would be tempted to try JWT library (JSON Web Token) https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt
With .Net but it is a little more work:
http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/
Sourcecode: https://github.com/tjoudeh/JWTAspNetWebApi

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends quite heavily on your API structure, but I would recommend somethign like this:

Firstly you would need to use the [Nativescript Http](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/http) module. An implementation to get a an HTTP GET calls returned header might look like this:

```
http.request({ url: "https://httpbin.org/get", method: "GET" }).then(function (response) {
    //// Argument (response) is HttpResponse!
    //for (var header in response.headers) {
    //    console.log(header + ":" + response.headers[header]);
    //}
}, function (e) {
    //// Argument (e) is Error!
});
```

So your backend might return a JSON Web Token as a header. In which case on the success callback you would probably want to store your token in the applications persistent memory. I would use the [Application Settings](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/application-settings) module, which would look something like:

```
var appSettings = require("application-settings");
appSettings.setString("storedToken", tokenValue);
```

Then before you make an API call for a new token you can check if there is a stored value:

```
var tokenValue = appSettings.getString("storedToken");
if (tokenValue === undefined { 
    //do API call
}
```

Then with your token, you would want to make an API call, e.g. this POST and add the token as a header:

```
http.request({
    url: "https://httpbin.org/post",
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Auth": tokenValue },
    content: JSON.stringify({ MyVariableOne: "ValueOne", MyVariableTwo: "ValueTwo" })
}).then(function (response) {
    // result = response.content.toJSON();
    // console.log(result);
}, function (e) {
    // console.log("Error occurred " + e);
});
```

Your backend would need to check the `Auth` header and validate the JWT to decide whether to accept or reject the call.

Alternatively, there some nice plugins for various Backends-as-a-Service, e.g. Azure and Firebase

Comment: Thanks man. With your help I found a JWT guide : http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/16/implement-oauth-json-web-tokens-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2/